# How to stop player sprite passing through blocks with collision detection?

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I am trying to stop the player passing through blocks. I would like them to be able to land on the blocks but bounce away if there is a collision on the other sides of the block

I have previously tried changing the distance the player is reset to when they hit a block

Run every frame to check if there is a collision:

```
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, walls, False)
if hits:
    player.checkCollisionWall(hits)
```

Player Class

```
import pygame, time, Settings
from pygame.locals import *
vec = pygame.math.Vector2

pygame.init()

class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    ACCEL = 0.5 # Acceleration
    GFRICTION = vec(-0.2, 0) # Ground Friction
    AFRICTION = vec(-0.2, 0) # Air Friction
    GRAVITY = 0.8 # must be greater than 0.6
    JUMP_HEIGHT = 10
    START_X = 25 
    START_Y = 600
    WIDTH = 10
    HEIGHT = 10
    START_POS = vec(START_X + WIDTH/2, START_Y + HEIGHT) # point at bottom middle
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.Pos = self.START_POS
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT))
        self.image.fill((0, 255, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.Pos.x, self.Pos.y)
        self.vel = vec(0,0) # set velocity as a vector
        self.acc = vec(0,0) # set acceleration as a vector
        self.inJump = False
        self.tryingToJump = False
    def update(self):
        self.tryingToJump = False
        self.acc = vec(0, self.GRAVITY)
        self.move()
    def draw(self):
        # draw the rectangle
        self.Pos += self.vel + 0.5 *self.acc
        self.rect.center = self.Pos
    def move(self):
        # identify which keys are pressed
        pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.changeX("left")
        elif pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.changeX("right")
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.jump()
        # check player is on screen and place player where it should be if neccessary
        if self.Pos.y > Settings.WINDOW_HEIGHT:
            self.Pos.x = self.START_POS.x
            self.Pos.y = self.START_POS.y
        if self.Pos.x < 0:
            self.vel.x = 2
        if self.Pos.x > Settings.WINDOW_WIDTH:
            self.vel.x = -2
        # apply friction 
        if self.inJump: #in the air
            self.acc.x += self.vel.x * self.AFRICTION.x
        else: #touching the ground
            self.acc.x += self.vel.x * self.GFRICTION.x
        # move the player
        self.vel += self.acc
    def changeX(self, direction):
        # move left or right
        if direction == "right":
            self.acc.x = self.ACCEL
        elif direction == "left":
            self.acc.x = -self.ACCEL
    def jump(self):
        # jump only if standing on a platform
        if self.inJump == False:
            self.tryingToJump = True
            self.inJump = True
            self.vel.y -= self.JUMP_HEIGHT
    def checkCollisionWall(self, hits):
        self.lowestWall = self.highestWall = hits[0]
        for i in hits:
            if i.rect.bottom > self.lowestWall.rect.bottom:
                self.lowestWall = i # find the lowest wall that the player is touching
            if i.rect.top < self.highestWall.rect.top:
                self.highestWall = i # find the highest wall that the player is touching
        if self.vel.y > 0: # check if a block is below
            print("below")
            self.rect.bottom = self.lowestWall.rect.top
            self.acc.y = self.vel.y = 0 # set acceleration and velocity to 0 on the y axis
            self.inJump = False
        if self.vel.y < 0: # check if a block is above
            if not self.tryingToJump: # if the block isn't trying to jump (I have this in otherwise player doesn't jump)
                print("above")
                self.rect.top = self.highestWall.rect.bottom
                self.acc.y = self.vel.y = 0 # set acceleration and velocity to 0 on the y axis
        if self.highestWall.rect.top < self.lowestWall.rect.top and self.rect.bottom == self.lowestWall.rect.top: # I have this line in too make sure that the player does not snap to the side of the block it is in when it moves side to side
            if self.vel.x > 0:
                print("right")
                self.rect.right = self.highestWall.rect.left
                self.acc.x = self.vel.x = -self.ACCEL # set acceleration and velocity to -0.5 on the x axis
            if self.vel.x < 0:
                print("left")
                self.rect.left = self.highestWall.rect.right
                self.acc.x = self.vel.x = self.ACCEL # set acceleration and velocity to 0.5 on the x axis
```

When I tried this the player would land on blocks fine, but when they touch the bottom of a block the player would snap to the top of the block instead of bouncing off it. When the player jumps while moving into the block the player snaps to the top of the higher block.
[image]

Comment: How many objects are involved here? The way you're describing the problem, I assume that you want the player, when jumping upwards into a block, to bounce downwards but instead the player is warping to the top of the block?

Comment: @AndrewFan At the moment, I have about 100 25x25 blocks and one player. The player starts on a row of 25 blocks. And yes, the player is warping to the top

Comment: For starters, I would highly advise using the `elif` construct. I assume that only one of these blocks should trigger, after all. I don't know the level design but there are a lot of potential edge cases here. 

Where are you setting y acceleration and `self.tryingToJump`? I have a feeling that the player triggers the `self.vel.y > 0` case after a jump on the way down (accel still positive, and same with velocity) while still colliding with a single block above.

Comment: @AndrewFan I was thinking the same. Surely the second `if` should be an `elif`. The third one deals with the `x` coordinate so that should remain an `if`. I think there is a typo in the third `if` too: `self.highestWall.rect.top < self.lowestWall.rect.top` should be `self.rect.top < self.lowestWall.rect.top`.

Comment: @Valentino I have ````if self.highestWall.rect.top < self.lowestWall.rect.top ```` in too make sure that the player does not snap to the side of the block it is in when it moves side to side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my (not so vast) experience this kind of problems may arise when the player movement is not tested separatately for each dimension.

I suggest you to:

1. Separate x and y movements and collision tests, so that you can move your player along x, test for collision and fix x position if needed, and repeat the process for y.
2. Edit the `checkCollisionWall` method so that it takes a single block, not a list of blocks. If you separate x and y movements, player will collide with at most one block. So no need to seach for lowest walls and highest walls. Your code will be simpler.

Here I suggest you some edits. `move` has been split into `move_x` and `move_y`. `checkCollisionWall` into `checkCollision_x` and `checkCollision_y`.
I've also edited the `update` method: now it does the whole process described in point 1, so calling `update` will check for collision too.

```
def update(self):
    self.tryingToJump = False
    self.acc = vec(0, self.GRAVITY)

    self.move_x()
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, walls, False)
    for bhit in hits:
        player.checkCollision_x(bhit)

    self.move_y()
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, walls, False)
    for bhit in hits:
        player.checkCollision_y(bhit)

def move_x(self):
    # identify which keys are pressed
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
        self.changeX("left")
    elif pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
        self.changeX("right")
    # check player is on screen and place player where it should be if neccessary
    if self.Pos.x < 0:
        self.vel.x = 2
    if self.Pos.x > Settings.WINDOW_WIDTH:
        self.vel.x = -2
    # apply friction 
    if self.inJump: #in the air
        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * self.AFRICTION.x
    else: #touching the ground
        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * self.GFRICTION.x
    # move the player
    self.vel.x += self.acc.x

def move_y(self):
    # identify which keys are pressed
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
        self.jump()
    # check player is on screen and place player where it should be if neccessary
    if self.Pos.y > Settings.WINDOW_HEIGHT:
        self.Pos.x = self.START_POS.x
        self.Pos.y = self.START_POS.y
    # move the player
    self.vel.y += self.acc.y


def checkCollision_x(self, coll_block):
    if self.vel.x > 0:
        print("right")
        self.rect.right = coll_block.rect.left
        self.acc.x = self.vel.x = -self.ACCEL # set acceleration and velocity to -0.5 on the x axis
    elif self.vel.x < 0:
        print("left")
        self.rect.left = coll_block.rect.right
        self.acc.x = self.vel.x = self.ACCEL # set acceleration and velocity to 0.5 on the x axis


def checkCollision_y(self, coll_block):
    if self.vel.y > 0: # check if a block is below
        print("below")
        self.rect.bottom = coll_block.rect.top
        self.acc.y = self.vel.y = 0 # set acceleration and velocity to 0 on the y axis
        self.inJump = False
    elif self.vel.y < 0: # check if a block is above
        if not self.tryingToJump: # if the block isn't trying to jump (I have this in otherwise player doesn't jump)
            print("above")
            self.rect.top = coll_block.rect.bottom
            self.acc.y = self.vel.y = 0 # set acceleration and velocity to 0 on the y axis
```

This code of course is not tested, but even if doesn't solve your problem as it is, I think should put you in the correct direction.

Comment: When there is a block below the player, the bottom of the player is set to the top of the block. Therefore, when the player is standing on top of two blocks (the ground is made up of multiple 25x25 blocks) it is touching two at once. This also occurs when the player is touching the side of a block while standing on another block

Comment: I see. So the longer rectangles in your picture are composed by more blocks? In any case, I think my solution should work anyway, because the blocks have the same y.